# Map data to the custom objects(models) inside another class when retrieving data from server in http.get() method in angular cli?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I'm creating an application with Angular-Cli where I have many models and some of these models have relations representing the data tables so when I retrieve data from the server I want to map the data to these object

I tried to create another model which represents the view in my database like combining two different models but I don't want this since it keeps my app messy and too ridiculous.

```
export class Employee{
id:number;
fullName:string;
department: Department;
}

export class Department{
deptId:number;
name:string;
}

#inside my service
<-- department table | json -->
[
{deptId: 1, name: "IT"},
{deptId: 2, name: "HR"},
{deptId: 3, name: "Finance"}
]

<-- employee table | json -->
[
{id: 1, fullName: "George W Bush", deptId:1},
{id: 2, fullName: "Barack Obama", deptId:2},
{id: 3, fullName: "Donald Trump", deptId:3},
]

<-- retrieved data from view | json -->
[
{id: 1, fullName: "George W Bush", deptId:1, name: "IT"},
{id: 2, fullName: "Barack Obama", deptId:2, name: "HR"},
{id: 3, fullName: "Donald Trump", deptId:3, name: "Finance"},
]


employees: Employee[]
getData():Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.stringUrl).subscribe(data=>{
    employees = data;
});
}

<ul *ngFor="let employee of employees">

    <li>employee.fullName}}
         <ul>
            <li>{{employee.department}}</li>
         </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

1. George W Bush
   a.IT
2. Barack Obama
   b.HR
3. Donald Trump
   c.Finance
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking; how to create Employee/Department objects out the JSON data you get from the API?

Comment: Oh I see you want to give Employee some of the data from the department table?

Comment: Can you change your backend so that it does a query that joins the employee and department table so that department name is included in the employee response that is returned? This would be the first thing I'd try, otherwise you'd have to do two queries from Angular, firstly to get the departments, and then to get employees (then map department IDs to department names).

Comment: I want to retrieve a view from database and give it to `Employee` which includes an object of `Department` so for example when I write `employee.department.name` it should retrieve department name of that employee

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just change the backend so it returns department name for employee instead of ID? That seems simpler to me. There's no reason your front-end objects have to be the same as your database tables.

Comment: It is simpler but needs much more code in both sides so just I wondered if there is a way for that since angular lets you to create custom objects so there must be a way for that

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments I think the best thing to do would be to modify the backend to return Employee objects with the department name already included, e.g. using an SQL JOIN. However if you didn't want to do that you could do something like the below:

**Component template**

Here we're letting the template handle the subscription to the observable for us by using an async pipe, instead of subscribing in the component as in your original example.

```html
<ul *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async">
  <li>
    {{employee.fullName}}
    <ul>
      <li>{{employee.department.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Component**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  employees$: Observable<Employee[]>;

  constructor(private readonly employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    this.employees$ = this.employeeService.getData();
  }
}
```

**Service**

Here we make sure the request fetches departments first, then creates a map of them to pass to the `getEmployees()` method. The use of rxjs `switchmap` means that `getData()` will return the `Employee[]` we want.

```js
interface EmployeeResponse {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  deptId: number;
}

export class Employee {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  department: Department;
}

export class Department {
  deptId: number;
  name: string;
}

const employeesUrl = 'http://localhost:4201/employees';
const departmentsUrl = 'http://localhost:4201/departments';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EmployeeService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.getDepartments().pipe(
      switchMap(departmentsMap => this.getEmployees(departmentsMap)),
    );
  }

  getDepartments(): Observable<Map<number, Department>> {
    return this.http
      .get<Department[]>(departmentsUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(
          departments =>
            new Map<number, Department>(
              departments.map(department => [department.deptId, department]),
            ),
        ),
      );
  }

  getEmployees(departmentsMap) {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeResponse[]>(employeesUrl).pipe(
      map(employeesResponse => {
        return employeesResponse.map(employeeResponse => {
          const employee = new Employee();
          employee.id = employeeResponse.id;
          employee.fullName = employeeResponse.fullName;
          employee.department = departmentsMap.get(employeeResponse.deptId);
          return employee;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. In that case please accept/upvote my answer.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: "departmentsMap is undefined" why

Comment: I guess because `getDepartments()` is not getting the data from the server correctly. But I don't know how your server works.

Comment: in the constructor you were supposed to subscribe it otherwise it would not assign the getData() directly to employees$ however thanks for your solution it worked very fine and gave me a lot of idea but in the component we should subscribe otherwise we can not get data like below:
this.employeeService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
     this.employees$ = data;
})

Comment: As long as you use the async pipe like in my component template example then you won't need to manually call subscribe.